# EntityFramework SaveChanges stops working after error

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am using the Generic Repository/Unit of work code used on the Microsoft Contoso University sample:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

And it works fine (it saves, retrieves, updates, delete etc) until there is an error at the database level. In particular, I tried to make an insert in which one of the fields was too short for the text that was passed to it. Of course it failed. The error is trapped in a try/catch block, and then an error message is displayed. Problem is, after that, even when entering new information to the form (this is, valid, as in with the right text size), the SaveChanges method keeps failing, with exactly the same error (field XYZ must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '999'). It only stops until I stop the debug and I restart the execution of the ASP.NET project

For clarity purposes, this is the code I have:
(GenericRepository.cs)

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal DBORAContext context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(DBORAContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {

        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(object id)
    {
        TEntity entityToDelete = dbSet.Find(id);
        Delete(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
    {
        if (context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
        }
        dbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
        context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }                
}
```

(UnitOfWork.cs)

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable 
    {
        private DBORAContext context = new DBORAContext();        
        private GenericRepository<Activity> activityRepository;        
        public GenericRepository<Activity> ActivityRepository
        {
            get
            {

                if (this.activityRepository == null)
                {
                    this.activityRepository = new GenericRepository<Activity>(context);
                }
                return activityRepository;
            }
        }        

        public void Save()
        {                            
            context.SaveChanges();
        }                

        private bool disposed = false;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    context.Dispose();
                }
            }
            this.disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        } 
    }
```

And this is the class that calls the repository for this particular object (Activity.cs)

```
public class Activity
    {
        private static readonly UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();                

        public static POCO.Activity Get(Guid activityId)
        {
            try
            {
                var thisActivity = unitOfWork.ActivityRepository.Get(a => a.ACTIVITYID == activityId).FirstOrDefault();

                if (null != thisActivity)
                {
                    return thisActivity;
                }
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                
                new Logger(ex.Message);
                return null;
            }            
        }

        public static POCO.Activity Add(POCO.Activity activityToInsert)
        {
            try
            {
                unitOfWork.ActivityRepository.Insert(activityToInsert);
                unitOfWork.Save();
                return activityToInsert;
            }            
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //log.Error("Add activity error", ex);
                new Logger(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }

        public static bool Update(POCO.Activity activityToUpdate)
        {
            try
            {
                unitOfWork.ActivityRepository.Update(activityToUpdate);
                unitOfWork.Save();
                return true;
            }            
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //log.Error("update activity error", ex);
                new Logger(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }     

        public static bool Delete(POCO.Activity activityToDelete)
        {
            try
            {
                unitOfWork.ActivityRepository.Delete(activityToDelete);
                unitOfWork.Save();
                return true;
            }            
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                
                new Logger(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm using EF 4.3 on a Oracle database. Please help.

Comment: When `SaveChanges()` fails, the context remains unchanged, so all entities that were added to the context are left as "added". I really don't see why the tutorial you're using decided to reuse the `unitOfWork`. You would not have this problem if you created a new context (a new `UnitOfWork`) for each action that you're attempting to save.

Comment: Something like that is what I was afraid of. How do you suggest I should change my code?

Comment: I *would* think simply `using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork()) { ... }` in `Add` etc., and remove `private static readonly UnitOfWork unitOfWork`, but that leaves your POCOs attached to a now-disposed context, and that also causes problems. It should work if you make sure to explicitly detach your POCOs after saving (even in the case of an exception) though.

Comment: BTW, unrelated, but `GC.SuppressFinalize(this);` has no effect at all in that code, since `this` doesn't have any finalizer to suppress (nor should you give it a finalizer).

Comment: I added the using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork()) { ... } and it seems to work fine, but I don't uderstand the part about the POCOs being attached. Can you give me an example on how to detach a POCO after, say, Add?

Comment: The exact details depend on what interfaces your class implements, which properties are virtual, and how your classes get created. If your properties are virtual, and you create objects using `DbSet<T>.Create()`, you should be able to reliably get exceptions when you accidentally attach the same object to two different object contexts. As for how to detach, you've already got code that sets the `DbEntityEntry.State` property, you should be able to set it to `EntityState.Detached`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and this worked for me:

I removed the keyword `static` from this line:
`private static readonly UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();`

While using `static` the application keeps the same object during all its life and that's why the initial error remains even after entering new information in the form.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is your unit of work is a singleton. the unit of work needs a smaller scope. if this is a web app the http context is a good object to scope the UoW.

request.begin -> start UoW
request.end -> complete UoW

If this is a service then each request to the service can start/end a Uow.

If this is a rich client than you can scope to each UI form.

Comment: This is a web app (ASP.NET webforms, not MVC). Can you give me a more specific example on how to implement that workflow?

Comment: there are plenty of examples online. search for "entityframework context per request". most examples will probablly use MVC, but the same can be done for Webforms. this is specific to asp.net, not mvc or webforms.